# Allow string ID with ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the 2 following routes setup and they are working fine when a valid request is sent.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}");
```

I wanted to test some bad request to make sure the response was correct. I am trying to call the following Action in my controller.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    //output the id again
}
```

If i call `localhost:80/users/123`, i get a response back that is valid and it will output `123`. When i try to use an invalid `ID`, for example, one that contains letters it fails with the following error.

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:80/users/d1g'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found
>   on the controller 'Users' that matches the name 'd1g'."}

I can see whats going wrong. This request should be matching the first route, but instead its matching the second route. I have 2 methods called `Get`. One accepts an `ID` and the other doesn't require an `ID`. The one that does not require an `ID` returns a list of all records. I was having a lot of trouble with this and the route above is how i solved the issue.

Comment: It should not match first route. That route has a constraint that only allows numbers `new { id = @"\d+" }` for id parameter. And that is so that it wont clash with the second route mapping

Comment: I think for your first GET, you have specified a mask here: `new { id = @"\d+" }`, try removing it. But also i think you should have only one method with a simple decision: if `ID` is passed then return an Object, else return a list. But I'd take another way.

Comment: If i remove the constraint i get an error "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get() ". This makes sense as i have 2 get methods. One that takes an id and another that takes none in order to return a list of records

Comment: @DanHastings, two routes now conflict with each other if you remove the constraint

Comment: @DanHastings is this specific to UsersController? If so then add a specific route mapping for that controller.

Comment: @Nkosi no this is effecting all controllers. I have the same format for all controllers. They have 2 methods called Get, one takes an id and another does not. I could rename one of the Get methods to List, but then id need to make the action part of the url and it will look ugly for a POST request needing to send to /users/post

Comment: @DanHastings - It is unclear what your exact question is. Why would you expect the first route to match, when you specifically constrained it so it won't match when you pass a non-digit? What do you expect as a result when you pass a controller name that doesn't match if not the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the routes by removing constraint, updating route with action to avoid conflict and then switching the order.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithAction", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithId", 
    "{controller}/{id}", 
    new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: This resolves the issue, but in turn it creates the same issue i had before. Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get() on type. I want one controller to work like this /controller/ = call get(), /controller/id = call get(string id)

Comment: Bingo, this does the job. Dunno why, but I thought that hardcoding the action to get would cause issues but this seems to have worked perfectly